# How can i call a Oracle connection method in C# with paramaters?

Tags: c#, oracle

i have created a program in C# which inserts data into an Oracle database. It is pretty procedural though and i want to improve my program (and my knowledge) to use classes. I am having some trouble around calling a method with parameters. This is my code:

```
public class Oracle {
    public void Insert() {
    string oracleConnectionString = "User Id=" + l_orauser + "; Password=" + l_orapass + "; Data Source=" + l_oradb;
    using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionString)) {
        oracleConnection.Open();
        OracleGlobalization oracleSession = oracleConnection.GetSessionInfo();
        oracleSession.DateFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss";
        oracleConnection.SetSessionInfo(oracleSession);
        OracleTransaction oracleTransaction = oracleConnection.BeginTransaction();
        OracleCommand oracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand();
        oracleCommand.Transaction = oracleTransaction;
        oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        string oracleCommandText = "insert into T1 (C1, C2, C3) values (:l_c1, :l_c2, :l_c3)";
        oracleCommand.CommandText = oracleCommandText;
        oracleCommand.BindByName = true;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("l_c1", OracleDbType.Byte, 3).Value = l_c1;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("l_c2", OracleDbType.Date).Value = l_c2;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add("l_c3", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1024).Value = l_c3;
        try {
            oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oracleTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            oracleTransaction.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally {
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            oracleCommand.Dispose();
            oracleTransaction.Dispose();
            oracleConnection.Close();
            oracleConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want to call this with some parameters - the variables: l_orauser, l_orapass, l_oradb, l_c1, l_c2, l_c3, which are taken from the elements of the form, for instance textbox, datetimepicker. How can i do that?

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
var testOracle = new Oracle();
testOracle.Insert();
}
```

Comment: public void Insert(variable type variable name, second variable type second variable name ect.)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm

Comment: thank you, i had read about this type of call. i had understood though that there is a possibility using constructors? Or am i getting it wrong?

Comment: yes you could also make a constructor for your class that takes those variables

Comment: exactly this i wanted to find out how. Can you provide maybe a clear example so i can learn and understand?

Comment: Google is your friend :-)  http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/09/csharp-constructor-example-types-of-constructor-in-csharp.html

Comment: i have searched and read already a lot but didn't gasp the concept very well. that is why a asked for a concrete example for my code. for instance, do i get around declaring the variables in both main and Oracle classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82125/discussion-between-tim-freese-and-geo).

Answer (score -1):

ok, so after discussing with Tim Freese i have decided to use constructors and an array of prameters.

For reference i have added the code, maybe somebody will find it useful:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
string oracleUser, oraclePassword, oracleDatabase;
List<string> oracleArguments = new List<string>();
//0 = oracleUser
//1 = oraclePassword
//2 = oracleDatabase
//3 = oracleCommandText
//4+ = oracleCommand.Parameters
l_orauser = "schema1";
l_orapass = "schema1pass";
l_oradb = "db1";
oracleArguments.Add(l_orauser);
oracleArguments.Add(l_orapass);
oracleArguments.Add(l_oradb);
Oracle testOracle = new Oracle();
testOracle.Insert(oracleArguments);
}
```

And the Oracle class:

```
public class Oracle {
public void Insert(List<string> oracleArguments) {
    string oracleConnectionString = "User Id=" + oracleArguments[0] + "; Password=" + oracleArguments[1] + "; Data Source=" + oracleArguments[2];
    using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionString)) {
        //do something
    }
}
}
```